# Is this Q on topic at P.SE: Suggestions on which frameworks to port to

Tags: support, on-topic-definition

I wonder if a question like this one is on topic, at programmers.stackexchange.com. (If not, do you know some other StackExchange site where I could ask?)

The question is something like this:

*"To which PHP frameworks would you port a better discussion system?*

I suppose that popular and growing/non-declining frameworks would be appropriate. However I don't know much about the PHP world.

The discussion system would manage the comments following a blog post, or forum thread.

(I've ported to one PHP framework already.)"

"What kind of questions can I ask here?" — "[...] business concerns [...]"
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Downwoter / downvoters, would you mind explaining why? 1. Unless I ask the question above, how am I supposed to find out whether or not to post the question?  2. If you read the very last sentence of the question, you'd notice I thought the FAQ might allow it — or I don't understand what "business concerns" includes.

Comment: Don't worry about the down votes. Down votes on Meta don't mean the same thing as they do on the main site.  It just means someone doesn't agree with your point of view.

Comment: @Walter Okay, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a "which technology is better" question, which are called out in the FAQ as a type of question that is not appropriate for Programmers.

Comment: Okay I understand that point and I suppose I won't ask then. ((At the same time, I think "which framework is better" is a rather different question, and fairly much more subjective, than "which framework would you port X to". One doesn't have to like a framework, or think it's good, in order to port something to it? I don't like PHP at all actually, and think the framework I've ported to is rather weirdly written, but decided to port to PHP purely because of ... "objective" reasons :-) ))

Comment: The problem with a question asking "which framework would you port X to" is that no one answer can be "the answer", which is what StackExchange is all about.  Additionally, you would likely end up with a list of everyone's favorite framework, which isn't helpful either.